# IIS Error 500 triggered by web.config when adding ipSecurity entries

Tags: iis, http-code-500, web.config

The size of my web.config file is comfortably below max, but when adding +- 200  entries like `<add ipAddress="36.99.0.0" subnetMask="255.255.255.0" allowed="false"/>` I get a 500 error.

To avoid "do your research", these did not apply or fix:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24171031/web-config-size-limit-error

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22169084/cannot-read-configuration-file-because-it-exceeds-the-maximum-file-size

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59371572/iis-error-500-19-error-when-reading-web-config

Why the 500 error? And also, only control I have on this is via web.config as it's shared hosting and they don't do squat at their end.

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that the default maximum size for the **web.config** file is 250K.

> We have found an internal article that mentions that the reason for the 250KB limit is to reduce the chances of an attacker uploading a large web.config file. This is not just for migration of websites but also when deploying such large web.config files into existing website builds.

From [learn.microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/archive/blogs/httpcontext/cannot-read-configuration-file-because-it-exceeds-the-maximum-file-size-web-config)

It's not clear to me, but there may be other restrictions such as number of sections and number of lines.

The value can be changed here

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp\Configuration\MaxWebConfigFileSizeInKB  (REG_DWORD)
```

or here

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\InetStp\Configuration\MaxWebConfigFileSizeInKB (REG_DWORD)
```

There is documentation here [Description of the registry keys that are used by Internet Information Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/general/use-registry-keys)

**Why the 500 error** - because its an internal server error, which is what 500 is.

Comment: Yes I know 500 = server error, that was "Why would it trigger that".

I also mentioned I *know* that the size of the web.config is well within bounds.

Also I have no control over the registry as it's hosted and no-dice.

Finally, 100% of this I have read almost as cut-and-paste, so thanks but not fixing it, and "Learn Microsoft" link... really?

 I thought this was a forum for going to actual knowledge first-hand not some Google result.

Comment: @SKidd, yes you mentioned that you know it's within the size, but you had not mentioned physical size and it was a possibility that you were referring to the number of lines.  Finally adding approx 200 entries is increasing it a fair bit.

Comment: The failing web.config is only 177kb, so well below the default max size of 250k